# Sudden performance degradation running the same program in multiple instances on AMD ThreadRipper

Tags: performance, caching, mfc, multiprocessing, processor

Situation is:

- One and the same native, standalone (MFC, SDI) application is started in multiple instances on a 32 Core AMD ThreadRipper 3970X, 4400 MHz, Castle Peak CPU
- Each instance performs its main work load (neural network computations) in a worker thread and utilizes minimal additional CPU load in mainly two other threads (scripting and GUI/UI Thread)
- All instances are performing the same type of work based on the same application script which is run in all the instances simultaneously. Work share is based on different input files the instances process.
- The instances do not produce any graphic workload, actually they all run minimized
- The instances do not communicate with each other
- Each instance calculates its performance (in terms of processed work per time) continuously.
- The instances do not access the hard disk in any significant way. Just performance reporting every 10 s in a few lines of text file.

Now here comes the problem:

- When more than ~10 instance are started the performance of each single instance suddenly goes down massively, so that starting up more instances results in no increase of the overall computation performance anymore
- The overall CPU load doesn't increase anymore, the single cores are less and less used the more instances are running
- Below 10 instances everything scales up quite well
- On machines with less cores (tried on several machines with 2, 4 and 8 cores) everything scales nicely, too, and the CPU is finally 100 % busy when enough instances are running
- Each instance allocates about 3.2 MB of RAM when started and approx. 8,5 MB when it has loaded its files and is busy

--> Any idea what could be the limiting factor here or what I could try to find out?
My main thoughts are around the processor Cache. The ThreadRipper has 128 MB of L3 Cache shared by all cores. Once the Cache is eaten up by ~10 instances this could slow down the performance since the cores must access the external RAM then, right?

Then, however, the machines with fewer cores than the ThreadRipper are able to perform the same amount of work per core as the ThreadRipper does. Although they have significantly less Cache per core than the ThreadRipper and even one instance would eat up all their L3 core.

Additional question: The application is statically linked to MFC. Would it be beneficial for the Cache management/usage if I got it linked dynamically? I already tried but am still getting many linker errors since multiple other libs are included, too.

Many thanks for all hints/ideas.

Comment: About the statically-linked vs the DLL version of MFC, I would say there is no benefit as far as memory requirement is concerned. In the "new" Windows versions (NT and later) the system keeps a full copy of a DLL (code & data) for each process that loads it, and that's why the `HMODULE` and `HINSTANCE` handles are now the same. It was different in the old Windows versions (eg 3.11), where the code of a DLL was loaded only once and the data were instantiated for each process. But this is no longer the case, the code as well has to be instantiated per process, due to the Virtual Address Space

Comment: Great answer to this one, thanks! Saves me time trying to get things linked dynamically.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong!.. In the "new" Windows versions (NT and later) the system keeps only one copy of the DLL's code in memory, which is mapped into each processes address-space. The data of the DLLs are instantiated for each process. Which absolutely makes sense. In the old Windows versions even the data of the DLL were instantiated only once, system-wide! Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/advantages-of-dynamic-linking) and [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903). I'm terribly sorry...

Comment: So using the DLL version of MFC (and I would add C++ as well) might be worth trying. You need to install the MFC and possibly C++ "redistributable" or "runtime" on the client machine. Choosing the DLL option for MFC and/or C++ for your VS project shouldn't affect the "other libraries" therefore you should not be getting unresolved extrernals.  There is only one possible small disadvantage with this, static libs will only link the modules actually referenced, while DLLs are fully loaded, so only real testing will tell you what's best.

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts. That's actually great news since it opens up a possible path to take towards a solution. Once tried I will for sure give feedback about it here.

Comment: I managed to get the stuff linked dynamically (both MFC and CRT). Don't know what went wrong the last time. Actually, MSVC seems to not even allow to statically link to CRT in case you dynamically link to MFC. The code is approx. 46 % smaller now. However, when running the amount of RAM allocated for each process/instance is roughly the same as with the statically linked exe. Performance of the running instances goes down by about 10 to 20 % it seems. This is all on a 4 core machine, however, since I cannot access the 32 core machine right now. I will give an update on this later.